# How would I add a count for guesses and a best score in a simple Guessing game with multiple methods?

Tags: jgrasp

so I am having trouble with being able to have a proper TOTAL guess counter. my code needs to be basic so please dont offer me advice for doing anything you think is not trivial. currently, my code plays a game, then asks the user if they want to play again and its a simple Y or N. if yes, another games plays and if no then then game ends and it reports the results of every game played such: the total games, guesses per game, and the best game (reports game that had lowest guess count). my issues are being able to accurately count ALL THE GUESSES from every game. I am able to report results and track the total games played correctly but i cant figure out how to report a result that tracks the guesses per game, adds them all up, finds the smallest one.

```
 import java.util.*;  

public class Guess2{  

   // The range for what numbers the correct answer is allowed to be.
   public static final int MAX = 2;

   // Main method that calls the other methods for the game to run properly.
   public static void main (String [] args) {  
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);  
      introduction(); 
      int userGuess = game(console);
      int numGames = 1;
      System.out.print("Do you want to play again? ");  
      String putYesNo = console.next();  

      while (putYesNo.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {  
      System.out.println(); 
         game(console);  
         numGames++;
         System.out.print("Do you want to play again? ");  
         putYesNo = console.next();  
      }   
      if (putYesNo.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) { 
         System.out.println();
         finalScores(console,totalGuess,numGames);  
      }  
   }  

   // Method to play the guessing game using the input from the console(parameter) via the user playing the game.
   public static int game(Scanner console){  
      Random answer = new Random(); 
      int correct = answer.nextInt(MAX) + 1;  
      System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and " + MAX + "..."); 
      int userGuess = 0;               // This is used to prime the while loop.
      int numGuess = 0;                // This is used to start the count at 1. 
      int totalGuess = 0;    
      while (userGuess != correct){ 
         System.out.print("Your guess? ");  
         userGuess = console.nextInt();  
         if (userGuess > correct){  
            System.out.println("It's lower.");  
         } else if (userGuess < correct){  
            System.out.println("It's higher.");  
         }
         numGuess++;
      } 
      if (userGuess == correct && numGuess == 1){   
         System.out.println("You got it right in 1 guess");  
      } else if (userGuess == correct && numGuess != 1){  
         System.out.println("You got it right in " + numGuess + " guesses");
        }   
        totalGuess =+ numGuess;  
      return totalGuess;                 // This Returns the number of total guesses for this single game.
   }

   /* Method used to report the Users' final statistics of the game(s). 
      Uses information from the user input via the console, 
      the sum of guesses used for every game, and the total number of games played. */
   public static void finalScores(Scanner console, int totalGuesses, int numGames){  
      System.out.println("Overall results:");  
      System.out.println("    total games   = " + numGames);  
      System.out.println("    total guesses = " + totalGuesses);  
      System.out.println("    guesses/game  = " + iLoveRounding(1.0*totalGuesses/numGames));  
      System.out.println("    best game     = " );  
   }  

   // Method that introduces the User to the Game. 
   public static void introduction() {
      System.out.println("This program allows you to play a guessing game.");
      System.out.println("I will think of a number between 1 and");
      System.out.println(MAX + " and will allow you to guess until");
      System.out.println("you get it.  For each guess, I will tell you");
      System.out.println("whether the right answer is higher or lower");
      System.out.println("than your guess.");
      System.out.println();
   } 

   /* Method used to round the "guessing/game" ratio to 1 decimal place.
      The return value of this method returns the ratio in decimal form with only 1 didgit, so
      The scores method can report it properly. */
   public static double iLoveRounding(double round){ 
      return Math.round(round * 10.0) / 10.0;  
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look into making an integer ArrayList to hold all of the guesses per game. Then, when you are printing the results, you could first print out the whole ArrayList to represent the guesses per game, then call 'Collections.sort(yourArrayList)', which will sort the ArrayList from lowest to highest, then print out the first element of the ArrayList.

I'd recommend the integer ArrayList over a simple integer array, since the array will require you to define the size beforehand. An ArrayList can be dynamic, and you can change the size according to the number of times the user plays the game.